# Not unique table/alias (42000)

Tags: mysql, alias, mysql-error-1066

I get the error ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'STUDENT_TBL'

`select STUDENT,DATE,MARK from Assessments inner join STUDENT_TBL on` `Assessments,ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL,STD_ID inner join` `Visit_log,ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL,STD_ID where STUDENT_TBL,STD_ID` `IN (select ID_STUDENT FROM Assessments group by ID_STUDENT having avg(MARK)>3.7);`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `'.'` instead of `','` to access `Table_Name.column_name`.

```
select STUDENT,DATE,MARK 
from Assessments AS Assessments 
inner join STUDENT_TBL AS STUDENT_TBL on Assessments.ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID 
inner join Visit_log AS Visit_log on Visit_log.ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID 
where STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID IN (select ID_STUDENT FROM Assessments 
                             group by ID_STUDENT having avg(MARK)>3.7
```

Also use alias like `Assessments.ID_STUDENT` while selecting columns in select clause if those are present in more than one table

Comment: Now i have a error like: ERROR 1052(23000): Column 'DATE' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @ArtemMatrosov From which table you are referring `DATE` ?

Comment: From "Assessments" table

Comment: @ArtemMatrosov Use `select STUDENT,Assessments.DATE,MARK`

Answer (score 0):

If you use schema and tablename you must seperate it with dot like this

```
select STUDENT, Assessments .`DATE`,MARK from Assessments
inner join STUDENT_TBL on Assessments.ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID
inner join Visit_log.ID_STUDENT=STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID
where STUDENT_TBL.STD_ID IN (select ID_STUDENT FROM Assessments group by ID_STUDENT having avg(MARK)>3.7);
```

Comment: Now i have a error like: ERROR 1052(23000): Column 'DATE' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: i have add in my answer